# Chrome Apps, FileSystem API: chooseEntry method isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Edit: Found the error, but can't solve it, see below.

### manifest.json

```
{
    ...
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "persistent": true,
            "scripts": [
                "/js/background.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "notifications",
        "storage",
        {"fileSystem": ["directory"]}
    ]
}
```

### background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    window.open('/index.html');
});
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Achshar Player</title>
        <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="input" type="button">
    </body>
</html>
```

### index.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openFile'}, function(readOnlyEntry) {
            console.log(readOnlyEntry);
        });
    });
});
```

The method is called and so is the callback, but the file choosing dialogue never comes and the `readOnlyEntry` is undefined when the callback is executed. No errors on the dev tools, I am on 35.0.1916.153 m.

I have tried different variations of manifest declarations for `fileSystem` but since the function is not undefined in the script execution, the manifest is unlikely to be the issue.

When I use the [official example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/filesystem-access) extension of [fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) API the app works, so the chrome setup isn't the problem either. The problem seem to be my code, but I am lost here.

Edit: I added each file's content

### Edit 2: Found the error, now how to solve it?

I tried it in canary and realize the errors are shown via `chrome.runtime.lastError` and not the normal console. And this is the error I get.

> Invalid calling page. This function can't be called from a background page.

But this is not in background.js, this is in index.js which is called from index.html.

Comment: Rolled back edit: `fileSystem` API is unavailable for extensions

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Nope, plain ol' javascript. How would I call chrome APIs in jquery anyway? Edit: oh that `$` function is my own, not jquery. Just a shorthand for `getelementbyid` and `queryselectorall`.

Comment: Chrome Apps work fine with jQuery; it's just JavaScript. You'd call them like anything else. When your code includes `$('input')`, though, that looks like you're using jQuery to find elements in the page.

Comment: Right sorry for the confusion, will fix that

Comment: I would try document.querySelector('input'), but if your tag actually has `id="input"`, then getElementById should work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this in Chrome, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code that you've posted. I suspect that there is a problem with the way that you are loading the javascript, or possibly the context that it is running in (foreground page vs. background page)

For instance, if your JavaScript code snippet is actually in `main.js`, then that will run in the background page, and its `window` and `document` elements won't be the ones from your main page.

My test app looks very similar to yours, except that I have left out the `main.js` file from the manifest, and I have constructed a small `index.html` file, which loads a `foreground.js` script instead. This is the complete app:

### manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Stack overflow question test app",
    "version": "1",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "persistent": true,
            "scripts": [
                "/js/background.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "notifications",
        "storage",
        {"fileSystem": ["directory"]}
    ]
}
```

### js/background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create("index.html");
});
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <script src="js/foreground.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input id="input" />
    </body>
</html>
```

### js/foreground.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openFile'}, function(readOnlyEntry) {
            console.log(readOnlyEntry);
        });
    });
});
```

When I run this, I can click on the input element, and I see a file picker. Choosing an entry returns a FileEntry object, which is logged to the console (of the foreground page, *not* the background page. Right-click in the app window and select "Inspect Element", rather than "Inspect Background Page", to see the foreground console.):

```
FileEntry {filesystem: DOMFileSystem, fullPath: "/TestFile.rtf", name: "TestFile.rtf", isDirectory: false, isFile: true…} foreground.js:4
```

### Note:

From your original code, it appeared that you were using a framework like jQuery to search for DOM elements within your page. Chrome Apps work just fine with jQuery, but you have to be aware of when you are using a raw DOM Node object, and when you have a wrapped jQuery object.

Specifically, the line

```
$('input').addEventListener('click', function() {
```

would have caused you problems.

Replacing it with

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click'), function() {
```

would correctly find the element on the page, and attached the click handler to it.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I am doing too. I open an index.html tab from background.js which has index.js which has the `chooseEntry` call. I would be willing to believe the problem lies with the way I am loading the script but the function is available in the context and successfully executes. Which means the context is correct. And I am not using jquery, that $ function was my own shorthand for getelementbyid. One difference is that I am using `window.open()` instead of `chrome.app.window.create` because I want it to be a tab instead of a new window. I'll now try to use `chrome.app.window`

Comment: PS I just added each file's content like you did in your answer. And just tried in canary channel, same result.

Comment: Ah wait, I got something in canary, `Unchecked runtime.lastError while running fileSystem.chooseEntry: Invalid calling page. This function can't be called from a background page.` but it's not a background page, it's index.html. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: That sounds like you are still loading your handler in the background page, in main.js in your manifest, for instance. Inspect the background page, and in the "sources" tab you should be able to see what js files are being used.

Comment: I tried completely removing main.js from the app and manifest and reloading the extension so that index.js is the only file index.html loads. Still the same error. Have a look, http://i.imgur.com/i4Gu7Ar.png I am not using any $ function now. Nothing outside of index.js. And it is not loaded in manifest, only background.js is.

Comment: Ok found the problem, I am using window.open in background.js which apparently passes scope such that browser sees index.html as being loaded from background. Now I need a way to open a tab without using window.open. I can't use chrome.app.window.create because I don't want a window, I need a tab. Any ideas?

Comment: "I can't use chrome.app.window.create because I don't want a window, I need a tab." Does not compute. Chrome Apps don't have any relationship with the Chrome browser by design. You can open a tab in Chrome, but it's an arms-length operation after that, much as if you did a ShellExecute in Windows or something similar. Webpages can communicate with Chrome Apps using externally_connectable, but the tab itself won't have any Chrome App APIs available to it.

Comment: @Xan, I tried them first thing, they are not available for packaged apps. So can't use them.

Comment: @sowbug I don't want any control over the tab. Completely fine by that. My app's previous version works in a tab. 10k users out there will be very confused if it suddenly opened in a window. In Fact if anything, I want the tab to be completely free of background page. Which is kind of the problem here, it's not free. The scopes are connected. So any way for me to open a completely separate tab for index.html?