# unlimited file storage in chrome app

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to save an unlimited number of files to the users hard drive, without making the user click through a dialog box.

The only documentation I have seen on using unlimited storage is here: https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage, which says that it is only available to Chrome apps.

All of the examples I have seen of the Chrome `fileSystem` API suggest that in order to create a new file and write to it, the user needs to obtain an entry object from the `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` function, which means the user needs to go through a dialog box.

The regular `fileSystem` API looks like it can save a file to the user's extension sandbox without making the user go through a dialog box, but I'm wondering, does it have the `"unlimitedStorage"` permission that is only given to apps? It wouldn't shock me if only the Chrome API has that permission.

If I use the regular `fileSystem` API, I need to request the filesystem using `window.webkitRequestFileSystem` (I'm a little surprised `window.requestFileSystem` isn't working for me in Chrome), but the method takes `type` (`"persistent"` or `"temporary"`), and `size` (the bytes the app will require for storage) arguments.

You obviously don't do that in the Chrome API. However, the normal `fileSystem` API lets you request more storage when you need it using the Quota Management API, which is also documented on the page I linked above

And on https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#manifest, it says:

> The `"permissions"` field lets you specify HTML5 permissions that the app requires. By specifying `"unlimitedStorage"` and `"notifications"`, this app is able to use those HTML5 features without having to repeatedly ask the user for permission. During app installation, the user is told which permissions the app needs; installing the app implicitly grants those permissions for all pages whose URLs match those in the `"apps"` field of the manifest.

So I'm hoping that the `"unlimitedStorage"` permission simply means that I can just call `window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, anySize, successCallback)`, and instead of asking the user to raise the quota when it needs to, Chrome automatically does it.

**Question 1:** Does anyone know if that's the way it works?

However, if only the the chrome API has that `"unlimitedStorage"` permission, I could try creating a file entry with the regular API, and passing that entry into the Chrome API functions, therefore skipping the need for a dialog box, and gaining access to the `"unlimitedStorage"` permission.

**Question 2:** Is it possible for me to create the entry in one API and pass it to the other? I'm afraid the different API's might have different sandboxes.

The documentation on the `fileSystem` API's isn't great, so I figured I'd ask to see if anybody knew from previous experience. The fewer rabbit holes the better.

Comment: The scope of your question is not clear from it. Do you want to achieve "I want to save an unlimited number of files to the users hard drive" from: a webpage; a webpage in a hosted app; an extension; a packaged app?

Comment: My extension downloaded a blob from a website, and sent it to my packaged app, where I want to put it on my user's hard drive

Comment: Please edit your question: remove "my solution" section and post it as a separate answer. If you want to give credit to @Marc, just keep his answer accepted.

Comment: The Chrome docs you quote specifically refer to "Installable Web Apps", also known as "hosted apps" in Chrome documentation. They are _very_ different from normal Chrome Apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to avoid confusion, what here is being called a "packaged app" should be called a "Chrome App".

If the blob is to be used by any other app, you must obtain a `FileEntry` via `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` so the data will be written to the computer's file system where the user can access it. (You can obtain a directory that way from the user and save the retained entry, and use that without asking the user to make a choice every time.)

If the blob is only for use by that Chrome App, you can use the file API without calling `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`.

As for limits, you're correct that `unlimitedStorage` allows unlimited storage. In my experiments, despite the documentation, I have never been able to get a Chrome App to ask the user to authorize a specific amount. I use that permission, and there seems to be no limit. The Google documentation I've read on this appears to be inaccurate.

If you're writing to the external file system, after you've called `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`, there are no limits and you don't need `unlimitedStorage` permission.

Comment: I would like to keep the file in the app's sandbox, but I want to be able to access the file via url in the browser. I'm not sure what that counts as.

How would I use the api without calling chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry? just call chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry? It takes an entry argument, would that just be an entry obtained from the regular filesystem API?

Comment: You can't "keep the file in the app's sandbox, but ... be able to access the file via url in the browser". A sandboxed file not accessible except to the app whose sandbox it is in. It sounds like for your app you want the user to identify a staging area, which is done with `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` to choose a staging directory, then retain that entry (there's an API for that), store the retained enty in local storage, and use it whenever you want to save a blob. This way the files are available outside the app and the user has to choose the directory only once, during app setup.

Comment: What about the regular fileSystem APIs toUrl function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Entry
Does that not expose the file via url?

Comment: It embeds the data in the URL. Makes the URL potentially very large. It is not a reference to the file.

Comment: okay I think I understand. I'll work on it and post my code

Thanks!

Comment: does the solution you suggested allow me to save a file directly to the staging directory I made the user select on installation, or does it require the user to select another entry using chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry, as demonstrated in the "Save as" example [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage)?

Comment: Once the parent directory is chosen by the user, files and directories can be created in that retained entry with no further user interaction.

Answer (score 2):

My solution.

main.js

```
var chooseDirectory = function() {
  chrome.app.window.create("choose_directory.html");
};

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.reason == 'install') {
    chooseDirectory();
  }
};  

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {

  switch (message.type) {
  case 'saveBlob':
    var blob = new Blob([message.blob])

    chrome.storage.local.get('filesystemKey', function(items) {
      var fileSystemRef = items.fileSystemKey;

      chrome.fileSystem.restoreEntry(fileSystemRef, function(fileSystem) {

        fileSystem.getFile('test.txt', { create: true }, function(fileEntry) {

          fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
            writer.write(blob);
          });   
        });             
      });           
    });  
    break;
  } 
});
```

after using the chrome filesystem APIs, you use the regular html5 filesystem API to create the file.
As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284144/chrome-apps-filesystem-api-chooseentry-method-isnt-working) you cannot call the chooseDirectory function from the background script, so you need to create an app window  that can call it, which I do below.

choose_directory.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('click', function() {

    chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openDirectory'}, function(entry) {
      var homeDirectory = chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry(entry);

      chrome.storage.local.set({'filesystemKey': homeDirectory}, function() {
        window.close();
      });           
    });     
  });   
});
```

choose_directory.html

```
<script src="choose_directory.js"></script>

You need to choose a directory where you will store your files.

<button id="input"> Chose a place to save your files</button>
```