# Is it safe saving a fileSystem entry in chrome.local.storage?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I want to save a filesystem entry from [chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-chooseEntry) to chrome.local.storage, as suggested here: [unlimited file storage in chrome app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196265/unlimited-file-storage-in-chrome-app/).

Is this safe? Could another unwanted user/app look at chromes localstorage and change the value of the entry key I set in my app? Or is chrome.local.storage sandboxed just like app filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

localStorage is protected from access by javascript in pages in other domains, similar to the way that cookies are protected.  So, javascript access is only allowed from pages within the same domain.

Neither has robust security measures from being accessed outside the browser by external applications.

Whether that is safe enough or not is not something we could say as you haven't fully described the security needs of this particular element of your application.  You would have to judge what is safe enough.

I wouldn't store my banking passwords in localStorage.  But, I'm fine with storing application preferences there.  The wide gamut between those two options depends entirely on the specifics of the situation.

Comment: I gave this answer a +1, but would like to add that, despite all the talk about sandboxes, content security policy, hashed file names for local storage, and so on, local storage is still stored in files, on the local system. So what's there is neither more nor less secure than everything else on the computer. Another aspect of "safe" is safe from loss, and local storage is just as safe in this respect as anything else. If you back up the entire drive, you'll get the local storage, too.